# Run script only on specific URLs on AJAX website

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome

Trying to run script in my extension only on specific URLs.

The website is in AJAX and for some reason, when my background scripts check if it's the URL, it sends the message to content script and the content script executes. But that only happens on the homepage and not on Movie's page, which is how it should be, however when I go to the homepage and it executes the script and I go to the movie page, it still executes the script, and it shouldn't.

Shouldn't chrome.tabs.onUpdated update every time this is happening? Yet it doesn't.

Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Comment: Hello, What do you mean the website is in AJAX? AJAX usually refers to AsyncJavsacriptAndXml, which is for HTTP (API calls, etc)

Comment: It loads one and that's it. You have everything loaded and it doesn't actually "refresh", which makes my script run once, even though I can move around the website.

Comment: sorry man, you gotta post some code. What language did you write your page in. probably some HTML/CSS. are you using bootstrap, jQuery, or any other frameworks? can you post your code.